How to detect corrupt/damaged images (non-truncated and truncated)
Unfortunately, one of my backup drives with family photos got damaged and I had to use software to recover the files.
The recovery process extracts both intact and damaged files, but it is in order of 10k images (most of them are garbage).
I have tried to explore the PIL package, but I am still having issues making a script that detects all non-truncated (but corrupted) and truncated photos like the ones from the links below. See also the code I tried so far.
Can someone help find the right package and functions to accomplish this?
 from PIL import Image
 import os

 list_img=os.listdir()
 print(list_img)
 for filename in list_img[0:1000]:
 try:
    im=Image.open(filename).load()
 except:
    print("{} is damaged".format(filename))




Here is a link to the example of original vs output (corrupted) images: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/risonh4j5o4jtzyyt5dik/ADk7minzN2U4fMXocJz0YtI?rlkey=02k1kziz6m633nbmoi5qttmtr&st=3lhjuzr1&dl=0
I cannot upload the original photos here (they are too large).

what have you tried so far?  please post your code.

I edited the post to include the code.... i was having trouble to understand how to put code in post, but managed to figure that out

Can you post original image, not the output image?

try image.verify()

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/risonh4j5o4jtzyyt5dik/ADk7minzN2U4fMXocJz0YtI?rlkey=02k1kziz6m633nbmoi5qttmtr&st=3lhjuzr1&dl=0
@toyotaSupra  As requested, here is a link to the example of original vs output ( corrupted) images
Cannot upload the original photos here ( too large)

@ticktalk tried that already, but it basicly passes the entire check without triggering the exception
im=Image.open(filename).verify()

This question is similar to: Python Script to detect broken images. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.  Note that Googling for "detect corrupt image python" gives a number of other StackOverflow Q&As.  Removing "python" gives more (non-python) alternatives to consider ... if the goal is more important to you than the means.

What format are the images? JPEG? PNG? TIFF? Raw?

the following may be of help ( I haven't tried it myself as of posting - just need something to try it on ... )
https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageFile.html#

Managed to solve this issue using the following repository in GitHub:
https://github.com/ftarlao/check-media-integrity
Ran the script and managed to detect all the cases!
